# Select from a Database with a Variable in Python using SQLlite and an tkinter StringVar

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, tkinter

My database:

```
def create_table():
    c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Articles(description TEXT PRIMARY KEY, production_time INT, cost INT)')
```

In my GUI script I have the function call:

```
tkVar_article = []
tkVar_article.append(tk.StringVar(self))
tkVar_article[-1].set(articles[0])
tkVar_article[-1].trace('w', update_price)

def update_price(unused1,unused2,unused3):
        for x in range(0, len(tkVar_article):
            print(tkVar_article[x].get())
            position_cost = read_out_article_price(tkVar_article[x].get())
            print(position_cost)
```

Printing just `tkVar_article[x].get()` returns `('Test',)`

(tkVar_article[] is a list of tk.StringVar objects)

The function's body:

```
def read_out_article_price(desc):
    c.execute("SELECT cost FROM Articles WHERE description=?", (desc,))
    data = c.fetchall()
    return data
```

The return is an empty string

But the hardcoded query:

```
c.execute("SELECT cost FROM Articles WHERE description='Test'")
```

returns the correct value

What am I doing wrong?

Help is much appreciated

Comment: That is a common problem, but we really need to know how and where you exactly call that function. We will be helpful if your provide us a [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I hope it's easier to reproduce the code now

Comment: what is `articles[0]` which you use in `set(articles[0])` ? is it string `"Test"` or tuple `( "Text", )` ? `StringVar()` can keep only one string - if you put list or tuple then it converts it into string - for tuple it will be string `( 'Text', )` which you get.

Comment: use `print(...)` and `print(type(...))` to display variables and you will see what you get - and it should help you to find mistake.

Comment: print(type()) returns class string. I am slicing the strings now and that seems to work but i have no idea why the StringVar.get() methode returns such a weirdly formatted string in the first place.